# Two structure objects guaranteed same padding?

Tags: c, struct

I recently found out that structure assignment in C was as simple as a=b(I was using memcpy/memmove/custom functions so long).
My question is that: 
Are two objects of a same structure always guaranteed to have the same padding to make a=b work blindly?

Comment: Would be really bad if the language spec allowed and encouraged it but didn't guarantee it won't blow up, would it?

Comment: If you write `a = b` and the compiler doesn't complain, it's legal. If it does, it's not.

Comment: so using a=b has no side effects whats so ever and is the best way to assign 2 structs

Comment: Both `memcpy` and plain assignment basically do the same bitwise copying. Assignment of structures might even be implemented by the compiler using `memcpy`.

Comment: Yes but the problem of memcpy(overlapping memories) wont occur in a=b since the have 2 seperate memories

Comment: @StoryTeller: That does not speak to the question asked. They did not question whether `a=b` works but whether `a` and `b` necessarily have the same size. We could envision a language in which they did not have the same size, but assignment worked by making the necessary adjustments.

Comment: @n.m.: That does not speak to the question asked. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Structure assignment is not necessarily implemented as bitwise copying. An implementation may copy members individually without copying padding.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - You may interpret the question however you like. The OP pondered about the aspects which make `a = b` "work blindly" (their own words). I must certainly am on-topic.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You did not even answer the question of whether structure assignment could or does “work blindly.” Obviously it works, but that does not mean it must work blindly.

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD: Nothing has introduced a problem of overlapping memory.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Yes, I did not answer the question. The answer section is bellow. I posted *a comment*.

Comment: @n.m.: The question does not ask about incompatible structures in any way. It only asks about two different instances of the same structure type. There is no constraint violation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil we're obviously not on the same page and these comments are not the right place to start figuring out what each other has in mind. I will delete my comments as they contribute nothing to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In section 6.2.6, the C standard (draft N1570) discusses how types are represented. Clause 6.2.6.1, paragraph 4 says: “Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of *n* × **CHAR_BIT** bits, where *n* is the size of an object of that type, in bytes.”

The clear implication here is that, for any one type, there is an *n* that is the number of bytes used to represent objects of that type. So two different structures of the same type would have the same number of bytes.

That addresses the total number of bytes. We might also consider whether two structures might have some different internal arrangement of padding bytes.

6.25 20 says: “A structure type describes a sequentially allocated nonempty set of member objects (and, in certain circumstances, an incomplete array), each of which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct type.” So we see that a structure is intended to be composed of separate objects. In 7.19 3, the standard defines an `offsetof` maxro that takes the names of a type and a member and evaluates to the offset of the member within the type. Since this uses the type, not a particular object of the type, the offset must be the same for all objects of the type. Therefore, all members of a structure have the same locations in all instances of objects of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard places some conditions on the assignment operator, one of which must hold. This is one of the condition

> the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type compatible with the type of the right

Any type is compatible with itself.

The standard further says

> the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

A conversion from any type to itself is a no-op.

So your assignment is guaranteed to work and have the obvious effect. One doesn't have to appeal to sizes, alignments, or paddings.

Comment: I think that there was a lot of talking past one another in the comments above. I interpreted the question initially as asking in essence whether `offsetof` is guaranteed to yield the same result for different `struct`s of the same type, and left comments under a now-deleted answer speaking to this. I think that OP was a little confused, and the question seems unclear (I am the sole VTC). But, this answer is useful and may help to dispel some confusion. +1

Comment: The OP is asking whether all objects of the same type must have the same layout. The OP posits an object `a` of structure type and an object `b` of the same type and acknowledges one can be assigned to the other with `a = b`. The question asks whether a C implementation can merely copy the bytes of `b` into `a` (or, if it chooses, copy subobjects) or whether, in some C implementations, it might be necessary to examine the contents of one or both objects and rearrange the contents of `b` to put them into `a`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- I don't think that OP was that clear about their own question. I view the fundamental question to be about the layout of padding bytes, but OP motivation seems misguided. This answer asserts that such layout concerns are irrelevant to assignment; this seems to be a useful answer to what I find to be an unclear question.

Comment: My question meant: if the padding bytes added to 2 structure objects of the same structure type will always be the same. i.e will sizeof(strA)==sizeof(strB) where strA and strB are objects of the same structure. Hence a=b will work in such cases.

Comment: because i fail to see when to use memmove/memcpy when a=b is so much more simpler

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have answered that. The semantics of assignment can be expressed without any need to invoke the notion of layout and size. It works because the standard says how it should work, not because the layout and the size are the same. (Of course they *are* the same).

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD I wonder why you didn't hesitate to call memcpy even though you wasn't sure that the layouts are the same. What would happen if the layouts were not the same?

Comment: @n.m. -- OP has even expressed uncertainty about ["will `sizeof(strA) == sizeof(strB)`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453702/two-structure-objects-guaranteed-same-padding/47461216#comment81885757_47461216), independent of layout. Further evidence that the question post is unclear as it stands.